# why is firebase serve working fine but not firebase deploy?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, hosting

I have a react project which I want to deploy to firebase, It works fine when `firebase serve` but I get something like *You're seeing this because you've successfully setup Firebase Hosting. Now it's time to go build something extraordinary!* after `firebase deploy`,
why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: I found the problem. The `firebase.json` file was changed from

```
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
  }
}
```

to this

```
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [{ "source": "/service-worker.js", "headers": [{ "key": "Cache-Control", "value": "no-cache" }] }]
  }
}
```

And it worked, For more reference,
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/